# How to provide InfoPlist.strings file inside framework resources for NSCameraUsageDescription key localization

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a framework which wraps camera usage on iOS. Assuming that application that uses my framework already provides value for NSCameraUsageDescription in Info.plist file, I would like to make it possible to localize this value without any modifications of application project by providing InfoPlist.strings file for each language inside framework.

I tried embedding *.lproj/InfoPlist.strings for each language supported by framework. Unfortunately application that is based on this framework is not able to pick those up and use them when presenting permissions alert.

Is there a way to force application Info.plist use InfoPlist.strings files embedded in framework without copying them?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Application use value for NSCameraUsageDescription from Main bundle Info.plist

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible. Permissions will be taken from the main bundle info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

Go in `File->New->File` then select `Strings File`. Name this file `InfoPlist.strings`.

Click on it in the project manager and then click "Localize" in the right panel:
[image: Localize]

Pick the langages you need.
[image: Select all langages]

and add the keys in these just created files.